# How does SAML solve SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

After reading a few articles on SAML, including "SAML for dummies," and the SAML wiki article, I'm still entirely unclear as to how SAML actually solves the SSO problem. Suppose I take something like a Google account as an example. My understanding is that if I go to GMail and SAML is implemented, I will be redirected to an IDP, which, let's say, is Google's sign-in authority. My browser then goes there with a redirect, and I'm asked to log in. After providing the correct login info, I return to GMail with a token and SAML response encrypted with Google Sign-in's private key, which is then authenticated using GMail's public key, thus verifying that I am, in fact, who I say I am.

What's confusing to me, is that this seems to solve the problem of signing in the first time, or into a single application, but I don't understand what happens when I now go to Google Drive. Even if my browser saves the SAML token/response as a cookie, I would have to sign in again after the token expires, which, I read, is something like 2 minutes later. Moreover, even within the same application, requests to separate resources or endpoints seem like they would time-out in the same fashion.

The only hint I have is that, according to the wiki article, step 1 has the target resource at the SP check for "a valid security context." However, if GMail and Drive are separate applications which aren't communicating with each other, how would Drive know that I already have a valid security context?

Questions:

1. After the initial authentication, what information needs to be sent with future requests to the same or different application/endpoint? For example, perhaps the SAML assertion saved and resent with every request.
2. How is this information secured/verified?
3. What timeouts are associated with SAML's SSO, and how are the timeouts enforced on both the SP and IDP sides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are missing is that the Idp (Google's sign in page in your example) sets a session cookie on the first login. When you access Google drive as the second application, it has indeed no knowledge of the gmail session. Google drive does a redirect to the idp to get an authentication.

Now, the idp has an active session thanks to the cookie on the idp domain. That makes it possible for the idp to reply to google drive with a new assertion, generated from the persisted session information.

You're right that each assertion is normally only valid for a few minutes, but that isn't a problem as the idp can create a new assertion for each application.

For timeouts: The Idp can set a SessionNotOnOrAfter condition in the assertion to tell the SP that it must terminate the session at a given time.

Comment: So, to be clear, my browser contains a cookie for the IDP domain so that whenever I access additional applications registered with the same IDP, I am seamlessly redirected to the IDP domain, instantly authenticated due to the cookie, and thrown back to the page I requested without me noticing?